# Splitting multi-year period into several seperate lines of one year

Tags: r, date

In my current dataset (40.000 persons), I have multi-year data on healthcare consumption per person. Both the start and end-date of a utilisation of a certain package is used. For example: someone is using package A from 2015-03-20 until 2018-02-05.

Since my analysis (in R) requires annual data, I have to chop these periods of package A consumption up into bits of one year. I found these lines of code in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206794/split-date-rows-by-new-year):

```
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)

test %>% 
    ungroup() %>% # This isn't necessary if there are no groupings.
    split(rownames(test)) %>% 
    map_dfr(function(df){
        if (year(df$from_date) == year(df$to_date)) return(df)
        bind_rows(mutate(df, to_date = rollback(floor_date(to_date, "y"))),
                  mutate(df, from_date = floor_date(to_date, "y"))
                  )
    }
    )
```

However, this only seems to work for periods of two consecutive years (in his example 2008-2009). In my dataset, I have many cases in which someone is using a certain package for 3-4 years (like 2015-2018)

Could anyone help me with a code (or a rewritten version of the code I already tried) to cut these lines of data up into 2-3 separate lines with annual data? In the end, it should look somewhat like this (for the above-mentioned period of 2015-03-20 until 2018-02-05):

| Person_ID | Start date | End date | package |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2015-03-20 | 2015-12-31 | A |
| 001 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-31 | A |
| 001 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-12-31 | A |
| 001 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-02-05 | A |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might get you going.

As you potentially expand your data set per given `Person_ID` you are operating row-by-row iterating over your data frame/tibble.
For demo purposes, I go in smaller steps and rewrite the function. The principal idea is to create a dummy data frame/tibble with a row per year and fill in the correct start and end date.
It might also help you to define the function outside your "pipe".
This should help you to modify the code and adapt it to your problem, if you need to.

You did not provide a reproducible example, thus, I generate a simple 3 Person use-case.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)

<- tibble(
   Person_ID = c("001","002","003")
 , Start_date = ymd(c("2015-03-20", "2016-01-12","2015-05-05"))
 , End_date   = ymd(c("2018-02-05", "2017-05-12","2019-04-17"))
 , Package = c("A","B","A")
)
```

The first part gives a list of the individual use cases:

```
df %>% split(rownames(df))
$`1`
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Person_ID Start_date End_date   Package
  <chr>     <date>     <date>     <chr>  
1 001       2015-03-20 2018-02-05 A      

$`2`
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Person_ID Start_date End_date   Package
  <chr>     <date>     <date>     <chr>  
1 002       2016-01-12 2017-05-12 B      

$`3`
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Person_ID Start_date End_date   Package
  <chr>     <date>     <date>     <chr>  
1 003       2015-05-05 2019-04-17 A
```

With this we can now construct a function to work on each of these "cases".
The function below shows you how you can code such an expansion. There are more elegant ways to do this, but this version should get you going, if you need to adapt the function to your test data.

```
expand_over_multiple_years <- function(.df){
    # ---- check if we have a same year case and do nothing (aka return .df)
    if(year(.df$Start_date) == year(.df$End_date)) return(.df)
    
    # ----   create dummy tibble over all years
    ## ---   for this we create a tibble with rows per each year, i.e. seq_years
    ## ---   we set the dates to 1. Jan through 31. Dec
    my_df <- tibble(
         seq_years  = year(.df$Start_date):year(.df$End_date)  # sequence of years
        ,Start_date = paste(seq_years, "-01-01") %>% ymd() 
        ,End_date   = paste(seq_years, "-12-31") %>% ymd()
           ) %>%
    # ----   we add the additional columns to our dummy table to ensure we return
    ## ---   what is needed and delete the "helper" seq_year column
        mutate( Person_ID = .df$Person_ID
               ,Package   = .df$Package) %>%
        select(-seq_years)            # minus := "unselect" = delete column
    
    # ---- correct for Start- and End-date by overwriting the first and last date
    my_df$Start_date[1]         <- .df$Start_date
    my_df$End_date[nrow(my_df)] <- .df$End_date

    return(my_df %>% select(Person_ID, everything()))    # with the return we reshuffle the columns
}
```

Let's test the function for one case:

```
df [1, ] %>% expand_over_multiple_years()
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Person_ID Start_date End_date   Package
  <chr>     <date>     <date>     <chr>  
1 001       2015-03-20 2015-12-31 A      
2 001       2016-01-01 2016-12-31 A      
3 001       2017-01-01 2017-12-31 A      
4 001       2018-01-01 2018-02-05 A
```

Now wrap it all together in an iterative call:

```
df %>% split(rownames(df)) %>% purrr::map(expand_over_multiple_years)

$`1`
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Person_ID Start_date End_date   Package
  <chr>     <date>     <date>     <chr>  
1 001       2015-03-20 2015-12-31 A      
2 001       2016-01-01 2016-12-31 A      
3 001       2017-01-01 2017-12-31 A      
4 001       2018-01-01 2018-02-05 A      

$`2`
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Person_ID Start_date End_date   Package
  <chr>     <date>     <date>     <chr>  
1 002       2016-01-12 2016-12-31 B      
2 002       2017-01-01 2017-05-12 B      

$`3`
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Person_ID Start_date End_date   Package
  <chr>     <date>     <date>     <chr>  
1 003       2015-05-05 2015-12-31 A      
2 003       2016-01-01 2016-12-31 A      
3 003       2017-01-01 2017-12-31 A      
4 003       2018-01-01 2018-12-31 A      
5 003       2019-01-01 2019-04-17 A
```

If you want/need a dataframe/tibble output

```
> df %>% split(rownames(df)) %>% purrr::map_dfr(expand_over_multiple_years)
# A tibble: 11 x 4
   Person_ID Start_date End_date   Package
   <chr>     <date>     <date>     <chr>  
 1 001       2015-03-20 2015-12-31 A      
 2 001       2016-01-01 2016-12-31 A      
 3 001       2017-01-01 2017-12-31 A      
 4 001       2018-01-01 2018-02-05 A      
 5 002       2016-01-12 2016-12-31 B      
 6 002       2017-01-01 2017-05-12 B      
 7 003       2015-05-05 2015-12-31 A      
 8 003       2016-01-01 2016-12-31 A      
 9 003       2017-01-01 2017-12-31 A      
10 003       2018-01-01 2018-12-31 A      
11 003       2019-01-01 2019-04-17 A
```